# What is the use of -Wl,-rpath in while making the executable from the library

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries

We know that the command for making the executable is :

```
gcc -L/home/username/foo -Wall -o test main.c -lfoo
```

But if run ./test ,it will give error :

```
/test
./test: error while loading shared libraries: libfoo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

There are 2 solutionss for it:
1)

```
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/username/foo
```

2)

```
gcc -L/home/username/foo -Wl,-rpath=/home/username/foo -Wall -o test main.c -lfoo
```

my question is why do need to provide the library path to the loader??While making the execuatble I have explicilty mentioned the path such that the linker could create the excutable and I beleive there must be a refernce of the location of the library embedded in th execuatble

This a conceptual doubt i have ,plz clear it out.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a choice that the linker designers made -- but a good one.

The reason it is good is that it lets you build a library, link against it, and then install the executable and library without requiring a re-link.

The cost is that you have to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or the like to run the executable in the build tree; but normally this is no problem, as you can add the needed setting to `make check` or what have you.

If the default were flipped, then you would have to either relink at install time (which is a bit unfriendly since it is reasonably common to `make install` as root); or provide a flag to turn off the behavior at build time (but then you're back to the above...).

Answer (score 0):

`-Wl,rptath:` Its actually build the executable feeding the information that where the loader will check for the library for loading.
Lets me give an example with 2 cases:

1)
If I transfer the library and executable  to another machine and place them in 2 different location then I need to mention the path where the library is located by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.Then the loader will understand where to look for the loader while executing.

2)If i make the make the executable with `-Wl,rpath=` then I need to place the execuatble in the same path in another machine as the value of `-Wl,rpath=`.

So in simple terms we can say that we have the independency of placing the library with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`